# C - Imprimir o N-esimo número primo

Tags: c

O exercício pede para que o programa leia um número N e imprima o N-esimo numero primo informado. Ex: Entro com N = 3. O programa terá que imprimir O terceiro número primo, que é 5. Outros exemplos: N-esimo(2) = 3, N-esimo(5) = 11. Eu fiz o seguinte:

```
void nesimo_primo(int n)
{
    int a, primo, div, nesimo;
    primo = 0;
    a = 1;
    if(n == 1)
        nesimo = 2;
    else
    {
        for(nesimo = 3; nesimo <= 1000; nesimo++)
        {
            for(div = 2; div <= nesimo/2; div++)
            {
                if(nesimo%div != 0)
                    primo++;
                if(primo == 1)
                    a = a + 1;
            }
            if(a == n)
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("N-esimo(%d) = %d\n", a, nesimo);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se a lógica faz sentido e o que pode estar errado para o programa não estar funcionando corretamente.

Comment: se alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta para marcar sua pergunta como respondida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void nesimo_primo(int n){
int a, primo, div, nesimo;

primo = 1; //primo se inicia com 1

a = 1;

if(n == 1)
    nesimo = 2;
else
{
    for(nesimo = 3; nesimo <= 1000; nesimo++)
    {
        for(div = 2; div <= nesimo/2; div++)
        {
            if(nesimo%div == 0) // se em algum momento durante o loop, a divisao der exata, sinalize q o numero nao é primo, e saia do loop
            {
                primo = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(primo == 1) //se depois de passar pelo loop a flag ainda estiver ativa, faca
            a++;
        else
            primo = 1;

        if(a == n) 
            break;
    }
}
printf("N-esimo(%d) = %d\n", a, nesimo);}
```

A premissa estava correta, se vc colocar um print no seu "if(a==n)" vai ver q ele nunca entrava ali, se mandar printar o primo dentro do segundo for, vai ver q ele se incrementa ate valores mto altos, pq vc nunca reseta o valor dele.

O problema é q seu primo só calcula ate o numero 1000, abaixo uma solucao diferente.

```
int PrimoOuNao(unsigned n){
    register int i;

    if( n == 2 )
        return 1;

    if( !(n%2) || (n == 1) )
        return 0;


    for(i = 3; i <= ceil(sqrt((double)n)); i += 2)
        if( !(n%i) )
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

unsigned Nesimo(int n){
register int i;

    if( n == 1 )
        return 2u;

    int contador = 1, primoAtual = 3;

    while( contador < n )
        if( PrimoOuNao(primoAtual++) )
            contador++;

    return --primoAtual;
}
```

Comment: Valeu Nefisto! Comparando o seu exemplo baseado no que eu fiz, eu consegui observar o que estava acontecendo de errado. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente é limpar os valores das variáveis de verificação, e sabendo que o número primo só é dividido por **1** e por ele mesmo, deve estipular o limite de divisões que ele pode fazer.

Para pegar o enésimo número primo, é preciso verificar quantos números primos foram encontrados, então é bom usar um contador.

Vamos iniciar o número primo em **1** para os resultados baterem, `n3 = 5`, `n5 = 11`. `count` é o contador que indica quantos números primos foram encontrados; `rest` é a soma do resto das divisões inteiras encontradas; `x` é a variável para percorrer o `for`;

```
int enesimo_primo(int n){
    int primo = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int rest;
    int x;
```

O contador, deve se manter sempre o mesmo até encontrar um número primo, então deve-se usar um `while` para a verificação;

```
    while(count < n){
```

O incremento do número primo deve estar acontecendo a cada *Loop* do `while`, e deve-se estar sempre limpando as variáveis de verificação, para uma nova verificação.

```
        // incremento do número primo
        primo += (primo<3) ? 1 : 2;
        rest = 0;
```

Para a verificação do número se ele é/não primo, usa-se o `for`, pois sabemos o limite do número.

```
        for(x=1; x<=primo/2; x++){
            if(primo%x == 0) // acrescenta divisão exata
                rest+=1;
            if(rest > 1) // encerra caso o número não seja primo
                continue;
        }
        if(rest == 1) // se rest diferente de 1, o número não é primo
            count ++;
    }
```

Por último resta fazer a exibição do valor em tela ou retorna-lo.

```
    return primo;
}
```

---

**`main:`**

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    int x = nesimo_primo(3);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = nesimo_primo(4);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = nesimo_primo(5);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = nesimo_primo(6);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

**`saída:`**

```
5
7
11
13
```

Comment: Obrigado, Brumazzi!